# Azure Custom Speech Service "non" response

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I've been using the (preview) CRIS speech to text service in Azure. For some short wav files, i get a correct text equivalent, but it is followed by "non". Is this a keyword meaning "non-word" or is this a bug? -- it happens both when i use the base conversational model, and also when i use a custom language model based on the base conversational model, but it does **not** happen with the "search and dictation" model.

for example, i send a noisy wav file of someone saying "yes" and i get back "yes non". If the wav file is not noisy this doesn't happen, and if the spoken text is two or more words it doesn't happen. it just seems to happen for noisy one-word files. what does "non" mean?

Answer (score 0):

After talking with the product group, this is apparently a bug in the current build of CRIS and will be fixed shortly. The "non" doesn't mean anything, it just appears when there are bursts of background noise.